# Face Comparison using Face++

Tags: python

I am writing a code in python for face comparison using facepplib library, the function face_comparing(app) takes image url to compare. i have some images stored in local disk which on which i want to work. i have no clue on how to convert local directory into url. when i give the path of local directory it say "Error: Failed downloading image from URL. The image URL is wrong or invalid."

```
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals

import json

from facepplib import FacePP, exceptions

face_detection=""
faceset_initialize=""
face_search=""
face_landmarks=""
dense_facial_landmarks=""
face_attributes=""
beauty_score_and_emotion_recognition=""
def face_comparing(app):
    """
    Compare two faces and decide whether they are from the same person.
    """
    print('[Face Comparing]')

    img_url1 = 'http://192.168.100.15/moazzam.jpg'
    img_url2 = 'https://media.wmagazine.com/photos/5a6a18f56c29fa0b4cf8e5a4/4:3/w_1536/tom-cruise-joins-instagram.jpg'
    cmp_ = app.compare.get(image_url1=img_url1,
                           image_url2=img_url2)

    print('image1', '=', cmp_.image1)
    print('image2', '=', cmp_.image2)

    print('thresholds', '=', json.dumps(cmp_.thresholds, indent=4))
    print('confidence', '=', cmp_.confidence)
if __name__ == '__main__':

    api_key ='xQLsTmMyqp1L2MIt7M3l0h-cQiy0Dwhl'
    api_secret ='TyBSGw8NBEP9Tbhv_JbQM18mIlorY6-D'

    try:
        app_ = FacePP(api_key=api_key, api_secret=api_secret)
        funcs = [
            face_detection,
            face_comparing,
            faceset_initialize,
            face_search,
            face_landmarks,
            dense_facial_landmarks,
            face_attributes,
            beauty_score_and_emotion_recognition
        ]
        face_comparing(app_)


    except exceptions.BaseFacePPError as e:
        print('Error:', e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the url path at img_url1 and img_url2 and code is running fine. See below.

```
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals

import json

from facepplib import FacePP, exceptions

face_detection=""
faceset_initialize=""
face_search=""
face_landmarks=""
dense_facial_landmarks=""
face_attributes=""
beauty_score_and_emotion_recognition=""
def face_comparing(app):
    """
    Compare two faces and decide whether they are from the same person.
    """
    print('[Face Comparing]')

    img_url1 = 'https://urbanasian.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Aamir-Khan.jpg'
    img_url2 = 'https://i2.cinestaan.com/image-bank/1500-1500/126001-127000/126991.jpg'

    cmp_ = app.compare.get(image_url1=img_url1,image_url2=img_url2)

    print('image1', '=', cmp_.image1)
    print('image2', '=', cmp_.image2)

    print('thresholds', '=', json.dumps(cmp_.thresholds, indent=4))
    print('confidence', '=', cmp_.confidence)
if __name__ == '__main__':

    api_key ='xQLsTmMyqp1L2MIt7M3l0h-cQiy0Dwhl'
    api_secret ='TyBSGw8NBEP9Tbhv_JbQM18mIlorY6-D'

    try:
        app_ = FacePP(api_key=api_key, api_secret=api_secret)
        funcs = [
            face_detection,
            face_comparing,
            faceset_initialize,
            face_search,
            face_landmarks,
            dense_facial_landmarks,
            face_attributes,
            beauty_score_and_emotion_recognition
        ]
        face_comparing(app_)


    except exceptions.BaseFacePPError as e:
        print('Error:', e)
```

**Output:**

```
[Face Comparing]
image1 = https://urbanasian.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Aamir-Khan.jpg
image2 = https://i2.cinestaan.com/image-bank/1500-1500/126001-127000/126991.jpg
thresholds = {
    "1e-3": 62.327,
    "1e-5": 73.975,
    "1e-4": 69.101
}
confidence = 92.107
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compare your local drive images, then try to the URL link for your local drive images from the website as https://postimages.org/ and use the same program with url link of your local drive images to get the result. I used the same and its working fine.See image link as https://prnt.sc/pi9duy ,which shows url link for local drive image.